# Formatting file in HTML output

Tags: sed, scripting, text-formatting, html

I have a little script that will format a log file with all failed logins for users on the system. I have written the script to output the data in a text file in this format (two columns with the number of failed login attempts in the first, and the user in the second):

```
1,325 Unknown  
505 root   
17 adm  
16 ftp  
etc...
```

I need this file formatted in HTML output on the console in this way (each line in the file be printed on a html line break):

```
<html>
<body><h1>Failed Login Attempts</h1> 
<br />1,325 Unknown 
<br />505 Root 
<br />17 adm 
etc....
</body>
</html>
```

What I currently do is save the file into a variable, and put that variable into the html like so:

```
file=$(cat finalo) #file name is finalo
#print to console
echo "
<html>
<body><h1>Failed Login Re...</h1>
<br />$file
</body>
</html>"
```

The output display's the entire file contents on one `html <br />`. My question is how can I get each line in the file to print on each `<br />`?

I have tried reading each specific line of the file, saving that into a variable, and then using that variable on each `<br />` line like so:

```
line1=$(sed -n '1p' < finalo)
line2=$(sed -n '2p' < finalo)
line3=$(sed -n '3p' < finalo)
```

And:

```
<html>
<body><h1>Failed Login Report</h1>
<br />$line1
<br />$line2
<br />$line3
etc...
```

This solution gives me the correct output, however, aside from this solution being messy, a major flaw exists if the file has a different amount of lines than the ones hard coded, it will not display.

Any help would be appreciated! This is homework btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier than you think:

```
echo "
<html>
<body><h1>Failed Login Attempts</h1>"

# The following line prepends <br /> before each line in finalo
sed 's|^|<br />|' finalo

echo "
</body>
</html>"
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy. That single line of code fixed all my problems! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use also a `while`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "
<html>
<body><h1>Failed Login Attempt</h1>"
while read line
do
    echo "<br />$line"
done < file
echo "</body>
</html>"
```

Or with a function

```
function r_lines()
{
    while read line
    do
        echo "<br />$line"
    done < file
    return $line
}

echo "
<html>
<body><h1>Failed Login Attempts</h1>
$(r_lines)
</body>
</html>"
```

Comment: These too solutions also worked! I do like the function solution. Having a Java programing background, I was always taught to separate functionality from logic. Thanks!